# Show returned result from controller in template

Tags: angularjs

I call function from HTML and I want to display returned result.

Here is html code:

```
 <td ng-init="'damages = list.getDamageEvents(soData.damagesId)'">
     {{damages}}
 </td>
```

here is function in controller:

```
self.getDamageEvents = function (reviewsId) {
    var t;
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/DamageEvent/GetEventsByReviewsId/" + reviewsId).then(function (result) {
         t=result.data;
    });
    return t
}
```

the getDamageEvents() function return some string.

But in template view I don't see any returned result.

> **EDIT:** I need to access getDamageEvents function as isolate scope.

Any idea why I can't see returned result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$http.get** return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can't return a result at the end of your function getDamageEvents, instead you should affect your result to a variable called *damages* in the success callback like this :

```
self.getDamageEvents = function (reviewsId) {
   $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/DamageEvent/GetEventsByReviewsId/" + reviewsId)
   .then(function (result) {
     self.damages = result.data;
   });
}
```

Then you can access the damages variable in your view

Answer (score 2):

Your function that recover the data should set `$scope.damages`.

```
self.getDamageEvents = function (reviewsId) {
    var t;
    return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/DamageEvent/GetEventsByReviewsId/" + reviewsId).then(function (result) {
         t = result.data;
         $scope.damages = t;
    });
    return t;
}
```

Don't know your full code, so I don't removed the `return t;` statement, but I guess you don't need it.

Comment: the t variable seems to be useless, I think the author created it in order to save the final result.

Comment: to use isolated scope, you can do self.damages = result.data

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
{{damages}}
```

Angular will check for a variable of name 'damages' in your scope. So you do you have a variable with that exact name on your controller scope? I.e.:

```
$scope.damages = ...
```

(Assuming you are not using controllerAs syntax).

Comment: No I don't.But I want to use isolate scope